# Кто то верит в Магомета, кто (—) в Аллаха, кто (—) в Исуса, кто ни во что не верит — даже в чёрта на зло всем…

Tags: тире

Нужны ли эти тирешки в «Песенке о перерождении» В. Высоцкого?

> Кто то верит в Магомета, кто (—) в Аллаха, кто (—) в Исуса, кто ни во что не верит — даже в чёрта на зло всем…

Comment: Прочитайте у Розенталя "Тире в неполном предложении". Там сказано, что тире вместо пропущенного слова ставится факультативно. Если есть пауза — ставим; если нет — нет. И да, _назло_ и _Иисус_ пишутся так, как я сейчас написал.

Comment: Мой комментарий тоже как ответ на ваш вопрос. В данном случае выбирайте знаки в соответствии с интонацией АВТОРА и ставьте те, которые он поставил.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Это авторские знаки, руки прочь от Поэта!

А "назло" пишется слитно.

А почему это нас не смутил "Исус"? Напрашивается же ведь?!

> Кто верит в Магомета, кто — в Аллаха, кто — в Исуса,
>
> Кто ни во что не верит — даже в чёрта назло всем…

Comment: Ответу я плюс поставлю, я согласен с ним.

Comment: Как *Иисус* писать?

Comment: Ни в коем случае: ломает размер стиха. Однако должен же был смутить "ошибочностью".

Comment: Старообрядцы именно в "Исуса" верят, так что вот такую отсылку к церковному расколу Высоцкий сделал. ))